# Background does not fill whitespace at the bottom of page when using min-height

Tags: html, css

The last media query (Resolution: 529x266) makes each of my blocks ("Work, About, Hire") have a min-height. But my background does not fill in the extra space. How do I make my background fill the extra space?
To see the white space make the codepen 529x266 or smaller.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpVBGZ

```css
html {height: 100%; font-size: 100%;}
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483914764278-6f2b1e39bba5?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1377&q=80&cs=tinysrgb")no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.work, .about, .hire {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.opacity {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 100;
}
span {
  position:absolute; 
  height:100%;
    width: 33.3%;
}
/* Text */
p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Hover */
.opacity:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
.work:hover, .about:hover, .hire:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Media Queries */
/* 529px at 16px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 33.0625em) {
  section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .work, .about, .hire {
    height: 33.3%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  span {
    height: 33.3%;
    width: 100%;
  } 
}
/* 266px at 16px */
@media only screen and (max-height: 16.625em) and (max-width: 33.0625em) {
  section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .work, .about, .hire {
    min-height: 38.3%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  span {
    min-height: 38.3%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="work">
    <div class="opacity">
      <a href="#"><span></span></a>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#">Work</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    <div class="opacity">
      <a href="#"><span></span></a>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="hire">
    <div class="opacity">
      <a href="#"><span></span></a>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#">Hire</a></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace is because the elements inside the body are overflowing and by default overflow is visible.

So why is the content overflowing? It's because `.work .about .hire` each have `min-height` of `38.3%`. Since there are three of them, the total `min-height` is > 100% therefore the elements overflow and you get the white band.

Change `.work .about .hire`'s min-height to 33% and adjust the font size or other properties of the item to fit within the height constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am actually trying to make my background bigger so it fills the overflow. The goal is to have a  vertical scroll, and have the background fill the overflow.

Comment: I wouldn't make overflow be a part of your design. It's hard to work with, and  it'll make your life super complicated. If you want scroll, you should do it the normal/safe way by making the height of your items a fixed size. E.g. set height of `.work .about .hire` to a pixel value instead of `38.3%`.